# How to use localStorage with TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce, local-storage

I'm trying to figure out how can I use localStorage with TinyMCE. The script below works with textarea but not with TinyMCE enabled. I'm not sure how can I get the editor instance by the element selector.

HTML

```
<textarea id="editor"></textarea>
<p id="logs"></p>
```

JS

```
  (function() {
        try {
            (window.localStorage.getItem)
        } catch (e) {
            return
        }
        var area = document.querySelector('#editor');
        if (!area.value) {
            area.value = window.localStorage.getItem('value')
        }
        updateLog(false);
        document.querySelector('#editor').addEventListener('keyup', function() {
            window.localStorage.setItem('value', area.value);
            window.localStorage.setItem('timestamp', (new Date()).getTime());
            updateLog(true)
        }, false);

        function updateLog(new_save) {
            var log = document.querySelector("#logs");
            var delta = 0;
            if (window.localStorage.getItem('value')) {
                delta = ((new Date()).getTime() - (new Date()).setTime(window.localStorage.getItem('timestamp'))) / 1000;
                if (new_save) {
                    log.textContent = 'Saved.';
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        log.textContent = ''
                    }, 3000)
                } else {
                    log.textContent = 'last saved: ' + delta + 's ago'
                }
            }
        }
    })();
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lah82v0s/5/)

Comment: tinyMce api has events you can listen to and methods to get and set content

Comment: I found this on the documentation `tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent()`. How can apply it in the code above? I tried replacing `document.querySelector('#editor');` but it doesn't seem to work. Any idea?

Comment: that would replace `area.value` when you set the storage

Answer (score 0):

I ended up ditching the localStorage function. The latest version of TinyMCE (v4.3) has an autosave plugin. I added `autosave` in plugins section, `restoredraft` in toolbar and `autosave_interval: "1s"` in tinymce.init.